# How to prevent widgets from being shown in notification bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-layout, android-widget, notification-bar

I have a code here for a simple webview. It simply displays a webpage. However, the top part of the webpage is shown stacked below the notification bar(As in some of the buttons on the top part of the page). How can I prevent this?
I know I can hide the notification bar/icons, but I want to show the contents of the webview widgets below the notification bar without hiding it. I also don't want to use an app bar. Kindly help me out

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late WebViewController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      )),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your webviw with `SafeArea`

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  WebViewController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: WebView(
              initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            ),
          )),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

output:

[image]